# MariaDB is not starting

Tags: linux, centos, mariadb, plesk

I using Plesk 17 onyx on CentOS 7. I have updated my server via plesk update manager and suddenly my database server stop working. I was using MariaDB as database server. Plesk is also not working.

When I tried to start, restart MariaDB, I found the following error as output.

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  -l mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-12-13 13:41:00 PKT; 10min ago
  Process: 8193 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 8192 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8164 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8192 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 13 13:40:57 ns*.ip-19***** systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB database server...
Dec 13 13:40:57 ns*.ip-19***** mysqld_safe[8192]: 161213 13:40:57 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
Dec 13 13:40:57 ns*.ip-19***** mysqld_safe[8192]: 161213 13:40:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Dec 13 13:41:00 ns*.ip-19***** mysqld_safe[8192]: 161213 13:41:00 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
Dec 13 13:41:00 ns*.ip-19***** systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 13 13:41:00 ns*.ip-19***** systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Dec 13 13:41:00 ns*.ip-19***** systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Dec 13 13:41:00 ns*.ip-19***** systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

I also have tried to repair mysql via following command of plesk

```
plesk help repair mysql
```

Logs in `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log`

```
161213 14:01:15 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.49-MariaDB-38.0 started; log sequence number 155782156
161213 14:01:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
161213 14:01:15 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown option '--safe-show-database'
161213 14:01:15 [ERROR] Aborting
161213 14:01:15  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
161213 14:01:16  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 155782156
161213 14:01:16 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
161213 14:01:16 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
```

Comment: what does /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log tell?

Comment: Can you check /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log and add it to the question?

Comment: @Orphans I have updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are reusing a MySQL config file from an older version for your MariaDB. Theres an error saying `unknown option '--safe-show-database'` and if you check docs relative to that option, you'll find it's deprecated:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_safe-show-database

> This option is deprecated and does not do anything because there is a
>   SHOW DATABASES privilege that can be used to control access to
>   database names on a per-account basis. See Section 6.2.1, “Privileges
>   Provided by MySQL”. --safe-show-database was removed in MySQL 5.5.3.

You have to go into your my.cnf or MariaDB startup script, find that option, and remove it.